# JPA: On delete cascade @OneToMany relationship EclipseLink

Tags: java, database, jpa, eclipselink, derby

I have these two entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@XmlRootElement
@CascadeOnDelete
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 15)
    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String username;
    //...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "username", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @CascadeOnDelete
    private Collection<Post> postCollection;
    //...
}
```

And:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POST")
@XmlRootElement
public class Post implements Serializable {
    // ...
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERNAME", referencedColumnName = "USERNAME")
    @ManyToOne
    private User username;
    //...
}
```

I have some posts attached to the same user. If I delete one of them it works right. But when I try to delete that user from the DB (using the EntityManager) I get java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException foreign key violation restriction.
Is there a way to delete all that posts when the user (their foreign key) is deleted? Simply an `ON DELETE CASCADE` SQL statement.
I'm using Derby (Java DB) and EclipseLink. Adding those `@CascadeOnDelete`annotations from JPA Extensions for EclipseLink is the last thing I've tried, with no success at all.

EDIT:
This is the code I use for removing an user (it´s a REST API)

```
@DELETE
@Path("{id}")
public Response remove(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    User u;
    if((u = super.find(id)) == null)
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    super.remove(u);
    return Response.status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT).build();

}
```

And, in the superclass:

```
public void remove(T entity) {    
    getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
}
```

Comment: With the mapping you have, it should happen automatically, since you have cascade = ALL. Removing the user should remove its posts. What is your code?

Comment: In that case, you probably have other foreign keys pointing at the user you're trying to delete. Read the message of the error: it should mention the foreign key name.

Comment: If you specify the CascadeOnDelete annotation, are you using JPA to create your tables, or have you added the ON DELETE CASCADE to the Post table constraint yourself?  This annotation tells EclipseLink that the database will remove the referenced Post entities, so it  doesn't, and might lead to your exception.

Answer (score 0):

Can we try adding the  ON DELETE SET NULL clause to the foreign key constraint in the POST table. This would help  to set the corresponding records in the child table to NULL when the data in the parent table is deleted. So if a username value is deleted from the user table, the corresponding records in the POST table that use this username will have the username set to NULL.